# Define an interface as String or Object in Tyescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to define the correct icon prop for the Button component. This prop could be an object, array, and string.

Button.tsx

```js
import React from 'react'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { SizeProp, IconProp } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'

export interface IconType {
  name: IconProp
  size: SizeProp
  color?: string
}

export interface ButtonProps {
  icon: IconType | IconProp
}

const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({ icon }: ButtonProps) => {
  return (
    <button>
      <FontAwesomeIcon size={icon.size} icon={icon.name || icon} color={icon.color} />
    </button>
  )
}

export default Button
```

Well, this are possible values for icon prop for the Button component

```js
import { faHome } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

<Button icon="home" /> // Icon prop as string
<Button icon={["fab", "github"]} /> // Icon prop as array string with only two positions
<Button icon={{ color: "red", size: "2x", name: "home"  }} /> // Icon prop as object with only "color, size, name" properties, color property can to be optional
<Button icon={faHome} /> // Icon prop as imported icon from library fortawesome
```

Well, the problem is, that I would like to use all the possible values, but I have an error message: `Property 'size' does not exist on type 'IconType | IconProp'`

It directs me to the IconProp source and notice that it has the following

```js
export type IconPrefix = "fas" | "fab" | "far" | "fal" | "fad";

export interface IconLookup {
  prefix: IconPrefix;
  // IconName is defined in the code that will be generated at build time and bundled with this file.
  iconName: IconName;
}

export type IconName = '500px' | 
  'accessible-icon' | 
  'accusoft' | 
  'home' |
  'acquisitions-incorporated' | ... more icons

type IconProp = IconName | [IconPrefix, IconName] | IconLookup
```

Well, so, How I can resolve this error? I'm not 100% proficient in typescript yet, I hope to learn a lot by solving this. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon
  size={icon.size}
  icon={icon.name || icon}
  color={icon.color}
/>
```

...you already assume that `icon` prop is of type `IconType`.

But you type that prop as a union of `IconType` and `IconProp`. And the latter, as seen in the shown IconProp source, has no `size`, `name` nor `color` properties.

That is what the error message is about: depending on the actual type of `icon` prop, you may not have the `size` property available.

This situation is described in the TypeScript documentation about [Unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#working-with-union-types):

> TypeScript will only allow an operation if it is valid for *every* member of the union. For example, if you have the union `string | number`, you can’t use methods that are only available on `string`

---

If you really want to stick with a "magic" prop that can take different types (hence the union), you will have to *discriminate* the types to [*narrow*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) them down, and to be able to work with them separately.

> The solution is to *narrow* the union with code, the same as you would in JavaScript without type annotations. *Narrowing* occurs when TypeScript can deduce a more specific type for a value based on the structure of the code.

For example in your case, we could do something like:

```
if ("name" in icon && "size" in icon) {
  return (
    <FontAwesomeIcon
      size={icon.size}
      icon={icon.name}
      color={icon.color}
    />
  );
} else {
  return (
    <FontAwesomeIcon
      icon={icon}
    />
  );
}
```